# Mapping between Wikivoyage article names and their Wikidata identifier

Tags: data-request, wikidata, wikivoyage, data-mapping

When I want to know the Wikidata identifier of a Wikivoyage article like [Barcelona](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Barcelona), I usually run this API call:

> wget --quiet -O - "http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwikivoyage&titles=Barcelona&format=xml&props=" | sed -e "s/.*id=\"//" | sed -e "s/\".*//"
>
> Barcelona -> Q1492

But now I want to get the identifiers for all articles.

How can I get them without making thousands of API calls?
And also without downloading the WHOLE Wikidata database, which is probably huge.
Is there a file that contains just the Wikivoyage article name to Wikidata identifier mapping?

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Sorry I did not remember my own question, I should have read it carefully. Indeed I ws asking for the identifiers of all articles, so your query is perfect. Could you please post it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dump that you want is [wb_items_per_site.sql.gz](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/latest/wikidatawiki-latest-wb_items_per_site.sql.gz). Though it contains mapping between article titles and wikidata ids for all wikis, so it's relatively big (~1.2 GB compressed).

And it's an SQL dump, so you can either import it into a MySQL database and query that, or you can try to parse it based on the unspecified (but reasonably stable) format.

Since you're interested in English Wikivoyage, look for `enwikivoyage` in the  `ips_site_id` column.

Answer (score 3):

[Some history](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T120198).

Approximately since April 2016 you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT ?item ?sitelink
WHERE 
{
  ?sitelink schema:about ?item .
# ?sitelink schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?sitelink schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikivoyage.org/> 
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fsitelink%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikivoyage.org%2F%3E%20%0A%7D)